# What Is the Right Term to Describe Relation of Object Size to Photo Size?

Tags: terminology, product-photography

I am in a product photography and was asked to take a photo with a product and make sure it takes 80% of photo space. Is there a right term used to describe this in photography? I did a few searches but could not find relevant information. Would either "Object to photo relation" or "object to photo ratio" be close to describe this?

Is there an acceptable standard that photographers adhere to when making sure that product optimally fills photo or it's up to one's personal preference?

Answer (score 1):

I did not met this kind of term yet but I think that you may use `fill rate` for that and be understood well.

Also, it is not misleading to say just "object size" or "object dimensions" in other cases of talking about photos because it always refers to perceptible object size. It happens so that photos are fit to media or resized to fit the media in most applications and the reproduced object size will always be defined by the relation of object size and frame size at the time of photographing or at the time of cropping.